# Storing data in the most significant bits of a pointer

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I've found quite some information about [tagged pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_pointer), which (ab)use the alignment requirements of types to store bits of data in their unused least significant bits.

I was wondering however, couldn't you do the same with the most significant bits on a 64 bit system? Even if you were to use the 16 most significant bits of a 64 bit pointer, you would still need more than 256 terabytes of RAM for them to overlap.

I know that in theory this is undefined behavior, but how would this behave in practice on some of the common operating systems (Windows/Max/Linux)?

And yes, I am aware that this is evil and dangerous, but that is not what this question is about. It is a "what if" question about pushing computer programs to their limits, not one about sane and portable software design.

Comment: You cannot do this if the system uses the full address space for virtual addresses. You _shouldn't_ do this on any system, because it's a very stupid and dangerous thing to do, in order to gain a few extra bits. Particularly on a 64 bit system: any reason you think you'll _need_ a few extra bits on your 64 bit system with some 16GB+ of RAM available?

Comment: @Lundin: Well I could see some usage on embedded systems. But I agree it should be thought twice before using such "hacks". And if,, never for general pointers or full-grown OS application code.

Comment: As it goes with similar questions, if you need to ask the question, then you definitelly should not even consider doing something like this.

Comment: @Lundin You would use this for the same reason people use tagged pointers. The pointers are usually aligned to 8 bytes, so even adding one extra byte would cause an array of those structures to take 16 bytes per element, effectively doubling your memory usage. Halving your memory usage is a significant optimization for many applications.

Comment: This reminds me of the old Macintosh days where they used the 8 MSB of pointers for storing stuff. With the 68000 processor it was OK because the address bus was only 24 bits wide. Nevertheless it was a stupid idea, because the trick didn't work anymore on later processors having more RAM.

Comment: @Hedanito And _why_ are the pointers aligned at 8 bytes? Most likely because that is the fastest possible width for the given CPU. If you decide to do some manual fiddling-around to save memory, you might be sacrificing performance. It really doesn't matter, the cornerstone in professional programming is: _don't do really stupid things_. They will add complexity, complexity will add bugs, bugs will cause your program to break. Saving a few bytes of RAM, in exchange for opening up great potential to turn your program into some buggy, crashing mess, is not a sane choice, simple as that.

Comment: @Lundin Relax. Sometimes hacks like this are necessary. By squeezing in three different values into one 64 bit value in a proprietary library I maintain I managed to more than double the performance of one critical operation (it was memory bound) allowing our biggest customer to not buy 60 more servers. Horrible hack, for sure, it also comes with two pages of comments  and an alternative implementation in case someone needs to maintain this code 20 years from now. It's all about trade-offs. And you can't make informed decisions about trade-offs unless you know the details.

Comment: @Art Then may I ask: is there any reason why you wouldn't store the effective part of the pointers in plain integers (like for example `uint32_t`) and store the completely unrelated data in another, separate integer? And then, whenever there is a need of the pointer, cast the integer back to the proper pointer type? "Thinking outside the box" should be done recursively.

Comment: @Lundin because uint32_t isn't enough to store a pointer. In this particular hack I mentioned I actually stored the magic values in `struct { uint64_t bits:16; uint64_t more_bits:2; uint64_t offset:46; }` and then the offset was added to a base pointer somewhere else to calculate the actual pointer. I haven't actually tagged pointers ever since I was working on a virtual machine in the 90s and needed the tags for mark-and-sweep. There are uses.

Comment: *stored the magic values in `struct { uint64_t bits:16; uint64_t more_bits:2; uint64_t offset:46; }`*  **6.7.2.1  Structure and Union Specifiers**:  An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bit-field. If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit.  (cont)

Comment: If insufficient space remains, whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or overlaps adjacent units is implementation-defined.  **The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined.  The alignment of the addressable storage unit is unspecified.**   Playing with fire like that is *necessary*?  Necessary to *what*? Proving you can write bug-prone, unreliable, non-portable code reliant upon undefined behavior?

Comment: @AndrewHenle It's necessary for saving my customer a few million EUR on hardware they won't need to buy for the next few years hoping that memory prices drop before they need to buy the next batch of servers with RAM the size of a small country. Btw. there's no undefined behavior anywhere in what I mentioned, unspecified and implementation defined I'm fine with. If you want to do standards lawyer yelling at least get the terminology right.

Comment: @Art It is true that bit fields have pretty much random behavior though, and should therefore be avoided. While for example a raw `uint8_t` array would give completely deterministic behavior. So, without knowing the details of your specific case, it would seem that you could have stored the data in a `uint16_t` and the pointer in a separate `uint8_t [6]` array.

Comment: @Lundin Our product has exactly two supported compilers: clang and gcc, on Linux/amd64 only because the one customer that was interested in FreeBSD switched 8 years ago and the customer that was doing tests on MacOS gave up laughing at the terrible filesystem performance. So in all supported configurations we know exactly how this will behave. When we need to support different compiler/OS combinations we'll cross that bridge then. This is nicely encapsulated in 25 lines of code in one file. Peoples uses of glibc-specific behavior will be much worse to deal with.

Comment: @Art Your code **ignores** the possibility that your bit fields do not properly overlap your pointer value and can interfere with actual addresses, thus your code is subject to **3.4.3  Undefined Behavior**:  *Possible  undefined behavior ranges from **ignoring the situation completely** with unpredictable
results...*  Hence, UB.  Period.

Comment: *So in all supported configurations we know exactly how this will behave.*  No.  You know how is **has** behav**ed**.  You do not know **why** nor **how** it behaves that way, you just **hope** that the behavior you have observed in the situations you have observed it under are sufficient to make it work.  You have *a few million EUR* at stake, and you rely on *hope*?!?!

Comment: @AndrewHenle Let me quote myself "then the offset was added to a base pointer". Oh and since we only do string pointers that way it is safe regardless of whatever alignment argument you want to make. And yes, I know exactly how it behaves, I've ported an operating system to 3 different architectures and I know what compilers can and can not get away with. GCC documents it (clang always does what GCC does), the SYSV ABI documents it. If this changes, then the ABI changes and all system calls, filesystems and shared libraries stop working.

Comment: On linux, do: `egrep -r 'int.*:[0-9]+;' /usr/include/` that's the things that will break if any compiler ever decides to change bitfield behavior. This is ABI. This doesn't change.

Comment: @Art You are jumping through hoops to defend your reliance on undefined behavior.  Lundin has already mentioned methods to do what you want without relying on UB.  Linux being dependent upon the unspecified behavior of one compiler is interesting - and not in a good way because that means it's built on UB - but that does not require lower standards elsewhere.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Unspecified is not the same thing as undefined. You're  mixing terminology you obviously don't understand. And Linux only depends on implementation-defined behavior here (same as I). Linux ABI is one implementation of the C standard, they define how their implementation behaves, so everything is well-defined.

Comment: @Art,  Unfortunately, since it is not specified in the standard (or as you say `implementation defined`) the next update to the compiler (or any of the libraries) can result in the current assumptions about the implementation being incorrect.

Comment: @user3629249 No, it can't. Implementation defined behavior can have stronger guarantees and does in this case. Linux has not changed their ABI ever. You can still run binaries from 1995. If an update to the compiler or any of the libraries broke the ABI, that update would be backed out and whoever did it would apologize. You know that thing `uname -p` prints? Changing the ABI means changing what `uname -p` prints. It means reinstalling every single machine in the world that happens to print the same thing. Good luck convincing the industry to reinstall the world.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you know your exact memory layout you can probably do it, but it's risky. The most common 64 bits systems for Windows/Mac/Linux are amd64. On them the machine only has 48 bit virtual addresses (for the foreseeable future), so you have 16 bits to play around in plus the lower aligned bits, theoretically.

Except. Half of the address space is negative; addresses go between [-2^47,2^47). So you can't be sure if the bits set in the pointer actually mean that your magic bits are set or you just have a negative address.

Except. Today, most, if not all operating systems put the kernel in the negative address space and put the userland in the positive address space. It makes certain things easier and faster to manage. So you could abuse that knowledge to assume that playing with those bits should be safe.

Except. I've never seen a guarantee from any operating system that this situation will remain forever (doesn't mean that one doesn't exist, I just haven't seen one). You might update your kernel one day and suddenly the operating system decided that userland is negative and kernel is positive‚ or userland gets more address space to play around in.

As long as you mask out the extra bits before you dereference your pointers, you will be safe *today*, but maybe not tomorrow. And when you build your code around an assumption like this, you deserve all the pain you get when your undefined behavior you get away with becomes undefined behavior you don't get away with. Painting yourself into a corner like this is not fun.

Comment: linux kernel doesn't want to break user space and if it is used by program wide spread it is unlikely that other os will break the software without an adaptation period.

Comment: Aren't these caveats a little overblown? The bits about negative address space can be ignored entirely (just leave bit 63 for your sign).