# What's the benefit of hiding data in the address of a pointer

Tags: c++

I'm tracing the source code of Error class in llvm.
http://llvm.org/doxygen/Support_2Error_8h_source.html

Conceptually, the class should hold two important data members, a pointer(Payload) to ErrorInfoBase and a boolean flag indicating if the Error has been checked.

However, the actual implementation of getter and setter of the boolean flag hide the flag in the pointer Payload.

```
bool getChecked() const {
    return (reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(Payload) & 0x1) == 0;
}
void setChecked(bool V) {
 Payload = reinterpret_cast<ErrorInfoBase*>(
             (reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(Payload) &
               ~static_cast<uintptr_t>(0x1)) |
               (V ? 0 : 1));
}
```

I wonder why not just using a boolean data member, and setting and getter the flag from it.
What's the benefit of storing the boolean flag in the address of pointer?

Comment: Obfuscation perhaps?

Comment: See [tagged pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_pointer) for an explanation, advantages, and disadvantages.

Comment: Related: [Storing data in the most significant bits of a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33955713/) and [What are the real life use cases for tagged pointers?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/213160/)

Comment: Tagged pointers might be an optimisation in cases where we are short of memory (e. g. on micro controllers), or if we have a huge amount of objects and might get performance gain by saving memory. If there were only the pointer and the bool, we'd double size requirements or would have to accept bad alignment. If not mandated by the use case already, such optimisation should be preceded by some analysis confirming that we *are* in need for, otherwise it is premature (root of all evil...).